# Which logic gate/circuit should be present between a, b & Y?

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, digital, boolean-algebra

### [image: How to complete circuit between a, b & Y ?]

Thanks for pondering over my question.
Above is a digital logic circuit with 2 inputs, & 1 output. I want following logic to be implemented in sequence :

1. b = 0, a = 0, Y = 0
2. b = 1, a = 0, Y = 1
3. b = 0, a = 1, Y = 1
4. b = 1, a = 1 should be explicitly avoided so that both a & b are not 1 simultaneously
5. Suppose step 3 is tried before step 2, then output should be 0, i.e., Y = 0.

Which logic gate or digital circuit will work for above sequence of logical ops ?    I tried with OR and XOR gates, but they don't satisfy condition 5, and sequential operation can't be enforced.
Can I use 2-to-1 priority encoder such as the one shown in figure below ?
[image: Priority Encoder]

Or may be some smart implementation of NOR SR latch ? Please let me know of your thoughts. Thanks ahead of the time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, while it is based on logic, you tagged it as circuitry which means it's more an electronic question and, therefore, off topic here.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I am removing circuit tag from my question.

Answer (score 0):

`f XOR a` seems to fit perfectly.

How is it that you feel it contradicts condition 1?

```
a b c F Y
---------
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 1
0 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 1 0
1 1 0 1 0
1 1 1 1 0
```